# Django rest framework custom serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to convert raw JSON:

```
{'code': 1, 'inner': {'x': 1, 'y': 1}}
```

To rendered serializer.data:

```
{'code': 1, 'inner_x': 1, 'inner_y': 1}
```

with django REST framework serializer.

Which code should be placed in serializer?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is better to have same structure in both server and client. You can create a class with x,y members named "Inner" and "inner" can be foreign key member in your original class.

To answer the question, you can override create function:

```
class InnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Inner
        fields = ('x', 'y')


class CostumeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    inner = InnerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('code', 'inner')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        inner = validated_data.pop('inner')
        return MyModel.objects.create(inner_x=inner.get('x', None), inner_y=inner.get('y', None), **validated_data)
```

- This is example code - I didn't run it

EDIT:
Take a look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

You can define the InnerSerializer with no model like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: I want to do it without django model. Data arrives to me from external service and i want set rules for conversion from one json to another

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://goo.gl/ZaxAQe)?

Where you overreide `.to_internal_value()` for deserialization and `.to_representation()` for serialization.

Comment: I found this lib http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/custom_fields.html#function-fields useful